# 'Undefined step:' error Cucumber In Intellij when running selenium cucumber code

Tags: selenium, intellij-idea, cucumber, cucumber-java

When trying to run Cucumber Selenium code then not able to run it. it says

'Undefined step:' and all test cases are getting failed.

Comment: Please provide more info and exact exception you are receiving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to give step definition file name in runner class.
your tests are failing because it's not getting step definition file please try below code if you have missed it in Runner class.

```
@CucumberOptions(
     features = "Feature"
     ,glue={"stepDefinition"}
     )
```